# Connection has not been fully initialized

Tags: javascript, asp.net, authentication, signalr

In my application the following console error occurs when I navigate to another page.

> Uncaught Error: SignalR: Connection has not been fully initialized. Use .start().done() or .start().fail() to run logic after the connection has started.

In layout page the scripts are in the following order.

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/jqueryUi")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/customCss")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jQuery")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/customScripts")
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>


  var progressHub = $.connection.parallelProcessing;
var flagDownload = true;
$(function() {
    progressHub.client.updateProgresssBar = function(progressPercentage, downloadedSize, totalFileSize) {
        debugger
        downloadProgress("", "", "");
        $("#downloading-progress").dialog("open");
        var progressObj = $("#progressBar").data("ejProgressBar");
        progressObj.option("text", progressPercentage + " %");
        progressObj.option("percentage", progressPercentage);
        $(".received").html("(" + downloadedSize + " ");
        $(".total-size").html("of " + totalFileSize + ")");
        flagDownload = true;
        if (progressPercentage == 100)
            $("#downloading-progress").dialog("close");
    };

    progressHub.client.noNetConnection = function() {

        if (flagDownload) {
            flagDownload = false;
            showalertdownload("@Message.Nointernetconnection");
        }

    };
    progressHub.client.closeProgressDialog = function() {

        $("#downloading-progress").dialog("close");
        enableEvents();
    };

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

    });


});

function updateConnectionID() {
    progressHub.server.updateConnectionID();

}
```

Please let me know is ther any solution to resolve this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give the rest of your javascript code calling your connection/hub?

Answer (score 1):

Basing my answer on your error message, it seems you are trying to access your connection or hub without waiting for it to be initialized.

Taken from the [ASP.NET SignalR Github wiki](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client):

```
// This callback will only run once
connection.start().done(function() {
    console.log("connection started!");
});
```

A more complete and detailed example to be found on [ASP.NET website](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client)

Comment: Hi bsoulier,Thanks for the update. Can you please tell me how to check whether connection has been initialized or how I can initialize it in layout page before start()?

Comment: Have a look at given links, you need to wrap calls done to your hub inside the function used in `done` as the `console.log` line above.

Comment: Hey Shivani, did that helped you out somehow?